# How to convert string to control?

Tags: c#, compact-framework, windows-ce

i have `string MyText` that hold "L1"

i have label control that his name is "L1"

is there any way to read label L1 using MyText ?

something like:  `TMT  = MyText.Text`

or: `TMT = ((Control)MyText.ToString()).Text;`

thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Find a control with specified name:

```
var arr = this.Controls.Where(c => c.Name == "Name");
var c = arr.FirstOrDefault();
```

or search within controls of specified type:

```
var arr = this.Controls.OfType<Label>();
var c = arr.FirstOrDefault();
```

**Edit:**

if you have an array of control names you can find them:

```
var names = new[] { "C1", "C2", "C3" };

// search for specified names only within textboxes
var controls = this.Controls
    .OfType<TextBox>()
    .Where(c => names.Contains(c.Name));

// put the search result into a Dictionary<TextBox, string>
var dic = controls.ToDictionary(k => k, v => v.Text);
```

(everything above requires .NET 3.5)

If you don have it, you can do next:

```
Control[] controls = this.Controls.Find("MyControl1");
if(controls.Lenght == 1) // 0 means not found, more - there are several controls with the same name
{
    TextBox control = controls[0] as TextBox;
    if(control != null)
    {
        control.Text = "Hello";
    }
}
```

Comment: _Controls_ has no _Where_ method for me

Answer (score 2):

An easier way is to do something like this:

```
string TMT = "myButton";    
// later in the code ...
(Controls[TMT] as Button).Text = "Hullo";
```

for instance.

Comment: It works just fine ... there are two overloads - one for ints and one for strings

Comment: If you are 100% sure that `this.Controls` contains specified name, you can `cast` type instead of operator `as`: `((Button)Controls["myButton"]).Text`. But it's better to check everything

Comment: It is not working, it throws exception of null reference exception

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
        foreach (var c in this.Controls)
        {
            if (c is Label)
            {
                var x = (Label)c;
                if (x.Name == "label1")
                {
                    x.Text = "WE FOUND YOU";
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```

However, best practice is to avoid such cases ... If you could speculate a bit more why you need this, there will probably be a better solution.

--edit:thanks for noticing that is/typeof ..

Comment: i have string arr[4] that contain "l1,l2,l3,l4" - and i need to read the text that in the label that named l1,l2,l3,l4.  how do to it ?
i try: ((control)arr[1].tostring()).text - but get error

Comment: You should use operator `is` instead of types comparison. Also should `break` on search success..